Problem. Let $A,B\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$. Prove that if A is an invertible matrix then $CF\left(A\right)CF\left(B\right)=CF\left(AB\right)$
Problem. Let $A,B\in\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$. Prove that if A is an invertible matrix then $CF\left(A\right)CF\left(B\right)=CF\left(AB\right)$
Solution. A is invertible therefore $CF\left(A\right)=I_{n}$
Thus $CF\left(A\right)CF\left(B\right)=I_{n}\cdot CF\left(B\right)=CF\left(B\right)$
We need to prove that if A is invertible then $CF\left(B\right)=CF\left(AB\right)$
Let $\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2},\dots,\epsilon_{k}$ be elementary matrices...
need to somehow get to the point where $CF\left(AB\right)=CF\left(B\right)$ as well
Note. CF stands for Canonic Form

$CF$ means canonical form as in rational canonical form or Jordan canonical form?   Then the claim $A$ invertible $\implies$ $CF(A)=I_n$ isn't usually true.

@Nothingspecial We use Gauss-Jordan Elimination in order to convert a matrix into reduced-row echelon form . So if A is invertible then $CF(A) = I_n$

Then you should mention this in your answer. Otherwise, it's ambiguous. In your case, note that $CF(X)= Y \implies \exists \text{invertible }Z \text{ s.t. }ZX=Y$. See if this helps you.

Another way to go about this, is as follows.
First show that applying elementary row operations corresponds to multiplying by elementary matrices on the left (undoing a row operation is still a row operation corresponding to to the inverse of the original elementary matrix).
Call two matrices row equivalent if you can transform one into the other by only applying row operations. Check that this is indeed an equivalence operation.
Any invertible matrix is row equivalent to the identity matrix.
The row-reduced echelon form only depends on the equivalence class a matrix belongs to (do you see why?). Multiplying by elementary matrices doesn’t change the equivalence class and by extension multiplying by an inverible matrix doesn’t either.
